# Polymer Object Attribute With Default Values

Tags: polymer

I want to set up an options object attribute in my custom element that will take default values when not supplied by user.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
    <my-element options="{{{
                option_1: 'val1',
                option_2: 'val2',
                allow_this: true,
                allow_that: false
            }}}">
    </my-element>
</body>
</html>

<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="options">
    <template>
        <ul>
            <!-- ... -->
        </ul>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('my-element', {
            options: {
                option_1: 'default_val1',
                option_2: 'default_val2',
                allow_this: false,
                allow_that: false
            }
        });
    </script>

</polymer-element>
```

The above code doesn't work as values specified in the element constructor always override those I am trying to pass in.  How can I set it up so that option values are set to those passed in and default values are only used as fallback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass object values into published properties using JSON in attributes, but it must be strictly valid JSON (http://jsonlint.com/).

In this case, try:

```
<my-element options='{
            "option_1": "val1",
            "option_2": "val2",
            "allow_this": true,
            "allow_that": false
        }'>
</my-element>
```

Notice the single quotes on the attribute, and the double quotes inside the JSON itself. The double quotes are required by the JSON specifications.

Note that this is not *data-binding*, and so it does not use mustache notation `{{ }}`. Instead, you are simply describing a string value in an attribute that Polymer will deserialize (`JSON.parse`) into an object.

Comment: What about passing `bindings` as values `options='{"option_1": "[[ajax.response]]"}'` ? Polymer does not convert it if in the component you initialise it as: `options: {}`

Answer (score 2):

Data binding doesn't work outside of Polymer elements. Either use an [auto-binding template element](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#bindingoutside) or wrap the usage of *my-element* in another custom Polymer element.

But then you'll get a parse error for your options expression. You need to put spaces around the object braces: `options="{{ { ...} }}"`.

You should also check the warning in the [Adding public properties and methods](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#propertiesmethods) section of the Polymer docs about initializing array and object properties.